# Why tomato is too small?

Tags: vegetables, plant-care, tomatoes

[image]

I bought it a month ago then moved it to a bigger pot and the tomato started to be red but still too small, it is cherry tomato but still too small and not tasty sweet at all.

Answer (score 2):

Tomatoes, and most soft fruits, need good sunlight to sweeten up as they  ripen. If you're growing indoors, whilst they will ripen, they won't be as tasty and sweet as they would if grown outdoors in warm/hot sunlight. This is why tomatoes harvested in summer are sweeter than those grown in greenhouses under artificial light/heat conditions in winter - the latter are certainly edible, but not so tasty. if your plant is not a small tomato like a cherry variety, they haven't reached full size because they're being grown indoors under ordinary house conditions, though lack of tomato fertiliser on a regular basis may also partially account for it - you haven't said what your care routine is.

Comment: Thanks so much! actually I am just a beginner in gardening :), I don't fertilize it, just water it and I keep it inside because it is cold outside especially in winter it is freezing.

Comment: Its  not freezing here (UK) but there's no question of growing tomatoes outdoors here yet,not before end  of May unless you  have a sunny greenhouse, so  I know the problem. Its pretty good you're getting tomatoes that ripen at all, whether they taste good or not... you can buy specialist  feeds specifically for tomatoes, one  of those would help with the size of the fruits, but not necessarily the flavour...